# Font-awesome icons disappear after using $.get() to retrieve HTML snippet

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I wanted to try creating a 'single-page' experience and I've done that by writing an event listener in jQuery for menu link clicks. When that happens, an HTML snippet replaces the markup in my main content `div`. For example:

```
//this is inside the 'on click'
$.get("includes/portfolio.inc", function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data)
}, "HTML");
```

Everything is working great... except that the list bullets I use from font-awesome disappear. They exist on the first, hard-coded page the user lands on but don't render when retrieved as part of a snippet. Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<h1>A Header!</h1>
<ul>
    <li><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\"></i> Example Link</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Is there a known reason for this styling to disappear? Is it possible the `.inc` extension on the snippets would cause a problem? The rest of the file remains unchanged, including the links to external stylesheets and scripts, and the rest of the markup renders with no issues. I would appreciate any help!

UPDATE: I added `console.log(data);` in the `$.get()` anonymous function and it's outputting the `<li>` elements with the `<i class="fa ...">` intact.

The rest of the imported markup adheres to my stylesheets, it just seems to leave out the font-awesome classes.

Comment: Could you include a link to what you have so far?

Comment: A link to the live site? Sorry, the content is not ready to be made public yet.

Comment: I would be happy to provide more information, however.

Comment: Add a fiddle of your code with the important info changed.

Comment: I've never used jsFiddle and I'm having trouble getting it to load the font-awesome stylesheet. Bear with me.

Comment: While loading this code into jsFiddle I realized that the double quotes in the `<i>` tag were being escaped by backslash characters. I removed them, the syntax is now correct, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the posted code the double-quotes are escaped with a backslash. This is unnecessary and caused the `<i>` elements to be rendered without the font-awesome classes. The attribute values `.fa` and `.fa-chevron-circle-right` weren't seen by the browser because the syntax was incorrect and so the styles weren't being applied to the elements.

This can happen when you are copying from a PHP or JavaScript file and the source being copied was escaped to prevent errors.